# MariaDB Bug with TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, timezone, mariadb

> In MariaDB 5.5 and before there could only be one TIMESTAMP column per
>   table that had CURRENT_TIMESTAMP defined as its default value. This
>   limit has no longer applied since MariaDB 10.0.

Source: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/timestamp/

I have the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE oauth_client_details (
  client_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  resource_ids VARCHAR(255),
  client_secret VARCHAR(255),
  scope VARCHAR(255),
  authorized_grant_types VARCHAR(255),
  web_server_redirect_uri VARCHAR(255),
  authorities VARCHAR(255),
  access_token_validity INTEGER,
  refresh_token_validity INTEGER,
  additional_information VARCHAR(4096),
  autoapprove VARCHAR(255),
  version bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '1',
  creation_datetime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  modification_datetime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  active tinyint(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '1'
);
```

**I need**:

1. the creation datetime to be filled with current timestamp on insertion
2. the modification datetime to be updated with current timestamp on update.

I did an insert and here are the values I got:

- creation_datetime : '2016-12-11 20:03:24'
- modification_datetime : '2016-12-11 **13**:03:24'

I was expecting these values to be the same, so why is it now different ?

I would like to store only UTC time and translated it to user locale 
at the last moment.

- My Spring server use UTC time.
- MariaDB :

  ```
  SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@global.system_time_zone;
  |SYSTEM|UTC
  ```

It's now 20:03 in my country, so I suppose the wrong value is the `modification_datetime` field.

I use `mariadb:10.1.17` official docker image without any modification to the image.

This is my insert statement :

```
==>  Preparing: insert into oauth_client_details(client_id,authorized_grant_types,access_token_validity,additional_information,active,client_secret,creation_datetime,autoapprove,modification_datetime,resource_ids,web_server_redirect_uri,authorities,refresh_token_validity,scope,version) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) 
==> Parameters: bo(String), authorization_code,refresh_token(String), 1800(Integer), {"companyId":1,"companyName":"testing"}(String), true(Boolean), $2a$10$h/0tc3qnZj/ZfRrNXf.oiuypEyYXJAJZdHPgy2ZMc1XMAntAMPK(String), null, true(Boolean), null, testinggroup/api(String), http://localhost:8080,http://dev:31735(String), ROLE_CLIENT(String), 3600(Integer), read,write,trust(String), 1(Long)
```

Does anyone ever had this ?

Edit: I have updated my docker Mariadb from version `10.1.17` to `10.1.19` the latest in date and I still have the same bug.

Comment: It appears if dates are different it was because I left in the code a creationDateTime = new DateTime(); It means the server DateTime use my local timezone while sql a different one

Answer (score 0):

It appears dates are different because I left in the code a `creationDateTime = new DateTime();` in the Model.

It means the server was using DateTime() for creationDateTime and database UTC.